# Connect to excel 2007 file using ADOConnection in Delphi7

Tags: delphi, excel-2007, delphi-7, isam, adoconnection

I want to connect to an `excel 2007` file(.xlsx) using `delphi 7`, so I used a `AdoConnection` and set its `connectionstring` property as:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\test\qm\Results-summary.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;IMEX=1";Persist Security Info=False
```

But when I active the `AdoConnection` i get this error:

> Could not find installable ISAM.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution. my mistake was using `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver for `excel 2007` file. I changed it to `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` driver and set the extended property to `Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=yes"`, now my connection string is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\test\qm\Results-summary.xlsx;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=yes";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False
```

and it works:)